# onActivityResult() not called anymore in stopped activity

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I have activity A, which is listening for events and If the event is received it starts new activity B:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
```

Now I'm in activity C and activity A is stoped. When A recives an event it starts B but after B is finished `onActivityResult` in A is not called.

The strange thing to me is that worked, but stopped after new build.

The method `onActivityResult` is created with annotation `@onActivityResult`.

Comment: Indeed, onActivityResult is called only for an active activity. Use broadcasts to communicate with inactive activity.

Comment: How you start  activity C?

Comment: C in my description was any other activity, first next activity is called with:

`Intent i = new Intent(this, TabsFragmentActivity_.class);
  startActivity(i);`
and then this activity can call another activity.

@cynaide yes, that is one of my ideas, but I'm curious because this was working before, even when user exits application with home button